# Is there a way to run sass on a scss file without parsing imports?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, minify

I am building up a workflow in gulp to build and minify my SCSS and JS - usual stuff.

I'm using Eric Meyer's css reset as follows:

```
@import 'reset.scss';

h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: "Oswald", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0 40px 0;
}

section h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "Oswald", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 40px 0 15px 0;
}
```

It's in its own file, imported.

Then I have a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('buildScss', () => {
    return sass(paths.style.src+path.sep+'*.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.bin))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.bin));
});
```

This runs sass on the CSS files, dumps them to a bin/style folder, changes the name to [name].min.css, minifies and saves.

The problem is that a) the sass process imports the reset css files and includes it in the main compiled file and b) when the minifier runs it doesn't just strip whitespace - it plays with the order of things and probably some other clever stuff. This affects how the CSS is actually processed and in this case the font-family from the reset (`inherit`) is now included *after* the main definition, resetting it after it has been styled.

```
h1,section h1{font-family:Oswald,Verdana,sans-serif}a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,article,aside,audio,b,big,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,output,p,pre,q,ruby,s,samp,section,small,span,strike,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,tt,u,ul,var,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:after,blockquote:before,q:after,q:before{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}h1{font-size:4em;font-weight:400;text-align:center;margin:20px 0 40px}section h1{font-size:2em;font-weight:300;margin:40px 0 15px}
```

I figure one option would be if I could leave the @import in place and not follow it when running sass but I can't find an option to do that.

I'd like to not rely 100% on gulp to construct the files (so I could still manually run sass on them) and to leave some reference in the file to the reset for clarity.

I also realise that I can remove the font-family definition in `section h1` as it is inherited and this solves the problem in this particular case. But it's easy to accidentally get into that situation again and it would be frustrating to constantly be debugging around it.

Any thoughts, ideas, solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your minifier, not with anything else.

Comment: What minifier plugin are you using? What version? Can you confirm that things are in the correct order after being processed by sass, but before your minifier? @Nit is probably right.

Comment: Thanks folks, I'm using gulp-minify-css 1.2.1 and yeah after the sass step it's still all in the right order - reset first followed by the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Nit and @jeradg - the problem was in the minifier settings. I don't know if it should be doing what it's doing (bug submitted - https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/681) but either way it can be stopped by setting a switch in gulp:

```
gulp.task('buildScss', () => {
    return sass(paths.style.src+path.sep+'*.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.bin))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss({restructuring: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.bin))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

The change would be the `restructuring` parameter in this line:

```
.pipe(minifycss({restructuring: false}))
```